# How to get rows on presto that have a certain key in a JSON column

Tags: sql, json, hive, trino

Let's say there is a stream of events in Presto, that have the following columns

`id, user, event`

Users may perform many events. Event is a JSON column. The JSON object may have a key called "login" or "email-verified". I'm interested in performing a query that retrieves all rows where event has one of those keys

I tried (maybe naively) with

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from database.table WHERE json_extract_scalar('email-verified', $.event) IS NOT NULL")
```

But all I see is the following error:

```
DatabaseError: {'message': "line 1:89: mismatched input '$'. Expecting: <expression>", 'errorCode': 1, 'errorName': 'SYNTAX_ERROR', 'errorType': 'USER_ERROR', 'errorLocation': {'lineNumber': 1, 'columnNumber': 89}, 'failureInfo': {'type': 'io.prestosql.sql.parser.ParsingException', 'message': "line 1:89: mismatched input '$'. Expecting: <expression>"
```

Which doesn't change if I use `table.event` instead of the dollar sign

All of this running on top of pyhive

Comment: FYI, as you're using PrestoSQL, i replaced `presto` tag with `trino` as per https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html

Comment: The `$.event` needs to be in quotes: `'$.event'`. What is `'email-verified'`? Is it supposed to be a literal string?

Comment: Yes a literal string. I discovered that you can also place the json path with brackets as in `$['email-verified]`